# run a local python script remotely within an environment

Tags: bash, ssh, python

I would like to run a local python script remotely but activate the proper environment within the remote machine first. For example, if running locally I would do:

```
source activate myenv
python myscript.py
```

I thought I could do this using ssh like so:

```
ssh user@host "source activate myenv && python" < ./myscript.py
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. It produces the error message:

```
bash: activate: No such file or directory
```

What's the best way to do something like this?

Comment: You need to specify the full path to activate script. Alternatively, you can skip activation and just specify the full path the python binary within the venv

Comment: whoa, pretty weird: your comment and an answer appeared at the same time.. what's the etiquette here, do i accept the answer or do you answer and then i accept?

Comment: If you feel the answer was good enough to mark as accepted, you should do so. I don't plan to create answer for this one.

Comment: ok then i guess i will wait for someone else to answer as the current answer clearly doesn't address the question

Comment: You can also answer your own question and accept it if you have a solution.

Comment: I don't have a good solution to this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to activate the virtual env if you just want to execute a script and exit. Activation of a virtual enviroment is just a handy way to replace the python executable by adjusting the `PATH`<sup>1</sup>. So,  the command

```
$ source path/to/myenv/bin/activate
$ python myscript.py
$ deactivate
```

can be effectively replaced with

```
$ path/to/myenv/bin/python myscript.py
```

So when running the script via `ssh`, just select the correct path to the `myenv`s python executable and you're good to go:

```
$ ssh user@host "path/to/myenv/bin/python" < ./myscript.py
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Other than that, the environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` is set and the env name is prepended to `PS1`.

Comment: yeh that's what i ended up doing. thanks for the answer; sorry, can't upvote due to my rep < 15

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently (July 2022). I was trying to do some maintenance on a remote production server running Django.

I could manually do this, but had a tough time doing it through a script.

```
ssh user@host
cd DjangoFolder
pipenv shell
python manage.py migrate
```

I tried

```
ssh user@host "/pathTo/python3 /separatePathTo/manage.py migrate"
```

that took care of finding the appropriate python and manage.py, but didn't have the virtual environment location in the Path (*which was needed for installed packages*).

The solution that ultimately worked for me is

```
ssh user@host "cd DjangoFolder; pipenv run python manage.py migrate;"
```

A few points to note:

- "pipenv run" is running my command in the appropriate virtual
  environment I would've created using "pipenv shell"
- "cd DjangoFolder" is getting to the appropriate folder, so that
  pipenv activates the correct virtual environment
- Including both commands in the same shell instance (*by
  having them in the same string, separated by a semi colon*), is
  important to retain context between the two commands.

Answer (score -1):

If you can execute `source activate myenv` in the shell, then activate must be a file in `$PATH`. find that file and specify a full path. It must be present on the remote computer. Or find out what this activate script does and just send assignments to the remote computer.